# Randomly froze 3 times and won't boot anymore

Tags: boot

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for the past 3 days, going very smoothly until it randomly froze today. I waited it out to see if it would go back, but it didn't and forced a shutdown. I turned it back on and it froze after the logon screen, forced it to shutdown once again and turned it back on. It worked for a little while and then froze again.

I was on Spotify, the PC froze, but I could still change between songs. As Chrome was also running, I could visit pages/open and close new tabs. As soon as I loaded a page, everything loaded and then the page crashed. The major problem was that the laucher bar wasn't visible, nor was the upper menu, along with the system options.

After forcing shutdown and restarting, the system won't boot, showing me the following message:

```
[0.135282] Errors parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[1.033914] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: priv: HUBO 6013d4 badf573f (19428200)
[1.033981] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: priv: HUBO 10ecc0 ffffffff (1940822c)
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan liked list found

/dev/sda2:UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. 
    (i.e., without -a or -p options.)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root file system on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.22.1(ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1)built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of commands

(initramfs) _
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I searched some more and got the answer in another question. If anyone else is having this same problem run

```
fsck /dev/sda2
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: The specific device `/dev/sda2` is likely to be different on somebody else's system. Read the error message carefully to determine which partition you need to run fsck upon.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that, thanks for bringing that up.